# $f(z) = xy + iy$ is nowhere analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that the function $f(z) = xy + iy$ is nowhere analytic.

**Attempt:**

$u_x = y, v_y = 1 , v_x = 0, u_y = x$

Hence the CR equations hold only for $(0,1)$. Doesn't it mean that the function is differentiable (analytic) at that point? So is the question wrong as it says "nowhere" analytic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note** You are confused with the difference between complex differentiable and analytic. Analytic at a point would mean it is complex differentiable on a *disk* around that point. Your function is not.

It is true that **on open sets** analytic means the same as complex differentiable. But in general analytic is a stronger requirement. Your set is NOT open.

Comment: How is the set not open?

Comment: @Archer In the Euclidean topology, points are not open but rather closed (and the only sets that are both are the empty set and the entire space).

Comment: It would perhaps be helpful to qualify "differentiable" in your answer by "complex differentiable" ("analytic" is unambiguous for complex valued functions of a complex argument, but "differentiable" is not).

Comment: @Archer Open means that for each point in the set you can find a small disk around it inside your set. Your set contains no disk of positive radius... Note that in $\mathbb C$ any open set is either empty or uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

No, the function is analytic at a point only if it is analytic on a disc containing that point.  CR equations need to be true on a nbhd of $x$.